# WBEM OpenPegasus limits of instances enumeration

Tags: c++, wbem

we are using C++ OpenPegasus library for getting data from storage array. It is version 2.13.0 compiled for Windows.

I have problem with Enumeration of instances or instancePaths of storage array with a lot of objects. I got just Pegasus::CIMException with no message and with error code:

```
/**
    A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific
    error code.
*/
CIM_ERR_FAILED = 1
```

My main question is. Does somebody know if OpenPegasus client has some limit for enumeration of objects? Something like max count of objects which can be enumerated in version 2.13.0 ? Unfortunately, I can't find any info on web.

Thanks for any tips, information.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Openpegasus does not set any limit on max count.

But As you are on Windows, You may check if there is some limitation on the resource usage by the OS.

Windows support of openpegasus is not very strong.